# Write Integer to XML Node in minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm using minidom in Python to create an XML formatted log file for completed tasks. Part of the process is to compare the last modified time of a file to the time that that files data was recorded into the log. I plan on doing that via:

```
if modTime < recTime:
  do_something()
```

For example, `foo.pdf` was modified at 10:40am, then at 10:46am the log recorded foo.pdf's modified time. So a portion of the log *should* look something like this:

```
<Printed Orders>
  <foo.pdf>
    <Date Recorded>
      1352486780
    </Date Recorded>
  </foo.pdf>
```

However, when I attempt to write the times in their integer formats to the XML file I get the error:

```
TypeError: node contents must be a string
```

So, my questions are:
Is there a way to write an integer to an XML file? (Preferrably using minidom as to not clutter my script with more imports)
If there isn't, is there a better way to compare the modified time I pull from the file itself and recorded time I pull from the XML file than converting the recorded time to a string, writing to the XML file, pulling the rec time from the XML file later on, and then converting that string back to an integer?

Also, in case you're wondering, the plan is to do once-daily purges of a directory, deleting `foo.pdf` and other files based on the comparison of their own mod/rec times. If `foo.pdf` hasn't been modified since it was entered into the log, it will be deleted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at the output you expect. How would XML know if that is an integer or a string. With XML in general, you have to say everything with tags. Thus, everything is treated as a string.

You do not need to convert the string to a int, unless the other time is an int, because the time-string will not become any longer than it is now for a really long time (over 3,000 years). However, I am not sure why you have so much dislike for doing that conversion. If it's really a big deal, use JSON.